# Turning off Thunderbird's new e-mail tray icon notification for selective accounts

Tags: windows-7, windows, thunderbird

I have some IMAP accounts in my Thunderbird that I do not want to be notified of new mail coming in. However, I do want to turn off e-mail checking for said accounts and I do not want to turn off e-mail notification for the other accounts.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Not natively in Thunderbird, but by using the [Mail Alert](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/addon/mailbox-alert/?src=search) extension you can customise when and where you get a notification.

Answer (score 0):

Not possible.  The toolbar notification is not dependent on email account.  The notifications can be **either** On or Off.